# Open mobile safari from inside of Opera Mini?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, opera, url-scheme, opera-mini

I currently have a website that does not function very well inside of Opera Mini.  I would like to display a message that informs the user that the website is best viewed in Mobile Safari, and provide the user a link that will open the URL in Mobile Safari.

I know that the reverse is true, by taking a link like http://www.apple.com and changing it to ohttp://www.apple.com you are able to navigate from Mobile Safari into Opera Mini.  However,  I cannot find information on if the reverse is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do this in Opera Mini. Opera Mini can hand off to the native browser (or player) for video content that it can’t play, but not for HTML content.